# Android emulator location elevation : getting very few location data

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, gps

Using LocationManager with a GPS_PROVIDER on API Level 23 on android emulator of Android studio.

Getting location every 5 seconds with a minDistance of 0:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, ll);
```

I get longitude and latitude correctly every 5 seconds, but the elevation very scarcely and randomly.

During one minute, `location.hasAltitude()` is `false`, and `location.getAltitude()` equals 0, and then I will get a correct value.

Is this because of the emulator hardware ? Can I get more data ?

Comment: Well on the emulator any GPS data is totally fake-  its unlikely your PC has GPS in it, and even if it does it may not be using it.  I'd try it on an actual device.

Comment: @GabeSechan Sure but I still need to be able to thest on a lot of hardware and api levels, I will not buy 2039233 smartphones, I need to use emulators

Comment: @NanoPsh API levels, yes.  If you're using the emulator to avoid hardware testing, you're going to be disappointed-  it isn't a hardware emulator, and isn't running the exact version of Android with all the patches, tweaks, etc an OEM uses.  So its going to be mediocre to bad at that (but luckily other than screen resolutions, which it can do well, you rarely need to actually do that).

Comment: But for GPS-  the GPS data is totally faked.  If you want to test vs realistic GPS, you should record what you get on a real device and replay it.  I wouldn't rely on anything you get from the emulator being even remotely realistic.  And unless your app requires you to do low level satellite access, I'd just isolate the subsystem so you can test the rest without relying on the emulator's GPS data.

Comment: @GabeSechan Okay, I see what you mean, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out most emulators are not made for hardware testing or hardware simulation, and their GPS data is not realistic.

What can be done is replaying data from a real device on the emulator. On different emulators this can be done by importing a GPX or KLM file exported from different GPS applications, from a real device, or from the emulated one if the application allows drawing arbitrary routes.